# How to log/get a report on threading performance in Windows?

Tags: windows, multi-core, threads, hyper-threading

So with programs like Process Explorer and Process Hacker you can see what the individual threads from a given process are up to. However as far as I can tell its just an active monitor with no way to *record* performance of a given program. What I want to do is to be able to run stuff like full screen programs for a test session and be able to look back at the results to see how the threads performed.

Comment: [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) has logging ... but I don't know if it logs performance.

Comment: You want to look into Windows Performance Recorder and Windows Performance Analyzer.  There are quite a few videos on this site which will guide you on how to use them.  https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-39-Windows-Performance-Toolkit

Comment: Performance Monitor (perfmon) has logging. But... what exactly do you mean by "how the threads performed"?